# Is there a way to not override the entire property with a sub model in Kohana?

Tags: php, orm, model, kohana, kohana-3

I have the following chain of Models:

```
Model_Auth_User
Model_Module_User
Model_App_User
Model_User
```

...where `Model_User` is the model I'm actually using and it's just a dummy class, while the others all have functionality.

My problem is that in `Model_App_User` I want to add a column to the model, say `employee_flag`. I need to add it to `_labels`, `_table_columns` and possibly others. Of course, if I put the following in `Model_App_User`:

```
 protected $_labels = array(
      'employee_flag' => 'Employee Flag',
 );
```

the entire array of labels is overwritten. Not what I want.

Once option I thought of was to add a property called `_override_properties` which I would process on initialize and merge with the properties in the object. But this fails as well because if I use it's in `Model_Module_User` it will overwrite whatever I've put in `Model_App_User`.

What other options are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 solutions to this. You can change the way ORM works by defining your labels in a method called `labels`. I guess it would be something like this:

```
public static function labels ()
{
    return array
    (
        'name' => 'First Name'
    );
}
```

Then in your child classes, it would be as easy as:

```
public static function labels ()
{
    $labels = parent::labels();

    // Add new or modify labels.
    $labels['last'] = 'Last Name';

    return $labels;
}
```

You'll need to modify how ORM retrieves the labels for this to work. If you don't have the time to modify how ORM works then **Zahymakas** solution of adding to the array in the child `__construct` is a good compromise.

Answer (score 0):

What about `$this->_labels['employee_flag'] = 'Employee Flag';`?

Comment: But that's can be done in the definition as `$this` doesn't exist yet. That'd need to be done in a method. So it would be possible to do that in `_initialize()`. I'm wondering if there's another solution that doesn't require adding another `_initialize()` (although not a bad solution).

Comment: Well, since you are trying to modify an property rather than (re)setting it, this either have to be done in some sort of init func, or there must be a method like "modifyProperty".

Comment: `_initialize()` is a method you need.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything without overriding. You either override the `_initialize` function, or the constructor.